# Add Short Date Format for Nemo File Manager

Tags: locale, nemo

I am using Nemo File manager for some time now and one of the things that annoyed me a little is the date format it uses for any of the date columns (Date Modified, Date Accessed, etc.). I know there is a setting to change the date format, but the options seems limited. Is there a way to add/set a short date format for the date columns? Something like **Mar 8, 12:59 AM** rather than **Tue 08 2016 12:29:52 AM EST**?

Here are some of the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the terminal a bit, first run `locale -a`. That'll tell you which locales are available to you according to `man locale`.

Now, I don't use the nemo file manager but let's assume the program can be invoked by running `nemo` in a terminal (as opposed to taking a GUI route for now).

Keeping the output of `locale -a` in mind, try various `LANG` options to see which one gives you the format most close to what you like:

`LANG=en_GB.utf8 pcmanfm` works for me with the PCManFM file manager. The date modified column with this command has the output like this: `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`.

Just default PCManFM gives me `Monday 15 August 2016 20:39`.

If you find a `LANG` option that you like, you could modify your `Exec` line accordingly in nemo's desktop file (after backing up the original .desktop file for safety). Alternatively, copy "nemo.desktop" or whatever it's called from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and modify the copied version.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! I tried your recommendation but it does not seem to work. The date format still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the program doesn't offer such an option, it would require a code change.

The program uses the full date/time format:

```
$ date +'%c'
Tue 30 Aug 2016 05:53:32 AM CEST
```

You are asking for something like this:

```
$ date +'%b, %_d %I:%M %p'
Aug, 30 05:54 AM
```

Only changing the locale probably wouldn't help much:

```
$ LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 date +'%c'
Tue 30 Aug 2016 05:55:50 CEST
```